# WebGL display framebuffer?

Tags: javascript, webgl, framebuffer, depth

I used the WEBKIT_WEBGL_depth_texture Extension.
And init the buffers below.
But how am I able to draw this framebuffer?? I'm totaly stuck right now. -.-

```
function InitDepthtextures (){


var size = 256;

// Create a color texture
var colorTexture = gl.createTexture();
gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, colorTexture);
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_S, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_T, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, size, size, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, null);

// Create the depth texture
depthTexture = gl.createTexture();
gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, depthTexture);
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_S, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_T, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.DEPTH_COMPONENT, size, size, 0, gl.DEPTH_COMPONENT, gl.UNSIGNED_SHORT, null);

framebuffer = gl.createFramebuffer();
gl.bindFramebuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, framebuffer);
gl.framebufferTexture2D(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, gl.COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, gl.TEXTURE_2D, colorTexture, 0);
gl.framebufferTexture2D(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, gl.DEPTH_ATTACHMENT, gl.TEXTURE_2D, depthTexture, 0);


//set to default
gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, null);
gl.bindFramebuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, null);
```

}

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You don't draw framebuffers. You draw textures. So, first you attach a texture to a framebuffer. Now, with that framebuffer bound, draw something, the result is drawn into the the attachments of the framebuffer. Next unbind the framebuffer and draw something using the textures you attached to the framebuffer to see their contents.

Example:

```js
const gl = document.querySelector('#c').getContext('webgl');

const vshader = `
    attribute vec4 a_position;
    varying vec2 v_texcoord;

    void main() {
      gl_Position = a_position;
      v_texcoord = a_position.xy * 0.5 + 0.5;
    }    
`;
const fshader = `
precision mediump float;
varying vec2 v_texcoord;
uniform sampler2D u_sampler;
void main() {
    gl_FragColor = texture2D(u_sampler, v_texcoord);
}
`;

// compiles shaders, links program
const program = twgl.createProgram(gl, [vshader, fshader]);
gl.useProgram(program);

const positionLocation = gl.getAttribLocation(program, "a_position");

// a single triangle from top right to bottom left to bottom right
const verts = [
      1,  1,
     -1,  1,
     -1, -1,
];   
const vertBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, vertBuffer);
gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(verts), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
{
  const numElements = 2;
  const type = gl.FLOAT;
  const normalize = false;
  const stride = 0;
  const offset = 0;
  gl.vertexAttribPointer(
      positionLocation, numElements, type, normalize, stride, offset);
  gl.enableVertexAttribArray(positionLocation);
}

// create an empty texture
const tex = gl.createTexture();
gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, tex);
{
  const level = 0;
  const internalFormat = gl.RGBA;
  const width = 1;
  const height = 1;
  const border = 0;
  const format = gl.RGBA;
  const type = gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE;
  const data = null;
  gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, level, internalFormat, width, height, border,
                format, type, data);
}

// Create a framebuffer and attach the texture.
const fb = gl.createFramebuffer();
gl.bindFramebuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, fb);
{
  const level = 0
  gl.framebufferTexture2D(
      gl.FRAMEBUFFER, gl.COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, gl.TEXTURE_2D, tex, level);
}

// Render to the texture (using clear because it's simple)
gl.clearColor(0, 1, 0, 1); // green;
gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

// Now draw with the texture to the canvas
// NOTE: We clear the canvas to red so we'll know
// so anywhere that shows up green is coming from the canvas texture
// from above.
gl.bindFramebuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, null);
gl.clearColor(1, 0, 0, 1); // red
gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
{
  const offset = 0;
  const count = 3;
  gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, offset, count);
}
```

```css
canvas { border: 1px solid black; }
```

```html
<script src="https://twgljs.org/dist/4.x/twgl.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="c" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
```

You can read more about this topic [here](https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-render-to-texture.html)

Comment: The jsfiddle no longer works. Also this answer requires that you use import some external library. Would be interesting to see how to do this with just webgl.

Comment: updated. It still uses an external library to compile the shader. You can read why [here](https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-boilerplate.html). You can also read about this topic in more detail [here](https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-render-to-texture.html)