# Stitch images together in WebGL using a framebuffer

Tags: javascript, canvas, webgl, framebuffer

This is something of a follow-up to my question [Draw textures to canvas async / in sequence deletes old textures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76195593/webgl-draw-textures-to-canvas-async-in-sequence-deletes-old-textures), but with a different approach recommended to me by a friend.  I am just learning WebGL, so bear with me.

#### My goal

- Load images asyncronously
- Render those images to a single webgl canvas in a side-by-side "tiled" fashion.  Each image will contain coordinates to dictate where in the canvas it should be rendered
- On each async image load, treat the whole canvas as a single texture, then apply some image processing in the shader to the texture as a whole

#### Using a framebuffer

My understanding is that you can create a framebuffer, render textures to it, and then render the framebuffer to a target texture, and then render the target texture to the screen.

```
// First I create the frame buffer, and a target texture to render to,
// and attach the texture to the framebuffer

const fb = gl.createFramebuffer();
gl.bindFramebuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, fb);
const targetTexture = gl.createTexture();

gl.framebufferTexture2D(
    gl.FRAMEBUFFER,
    gl.COLOR_ATTACHMENT0,
    gl.TEXTURE_2D,
    targetTexture,
    0
);
```

My idea is that on every image load, you can create a texture from the image.  After enabling the vertex attributes on each texture, you can then call `drawArrays`, which would then draw *to the framebuffer*.  After doing that, you should be able to unbind the framebuffer, then call `drawArrays` again, which should...draw the framebuffer to the screen?  This is where I am getting confused:

```js
// Let's pretend we have a few tile urls in an array for now:
tiles.forEach((tile) => {
  const image = new Image();
  image.onload = () => render(image, tile);
  image.src = tile.path;
});

function render(tileImage: HTMLImageElement, tile: Tile) {
    // look up where the vertex data needs to go.
    var positionLocation = gl.getAttribLocation(program, 'a_position');
    var texcoordLocation = gl.getAttribLocation(program, 'a_texCoord');

    // Create a buffer to put three 2d clip space points in
    var positionBuffer = gl.createBuffer();

    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, positionBuffer);
    // Set a rectangle the same size as the image.
    // see Appending of question for details
    setRectangle(
        gl,
        tile.position.x,
        tile.position.y,
        tileImage.width,
        tileImage.height
    );

    // provide texture coordinates for the rectangle.
    var texcoordBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, texcoordBuffer);

    gl.bufferData(
        gl.ARRAY_BUFFER,
        new Float32Array([
            0.0, 0.0,
            1.0, 0.0,
            0.0, 1.0,
            0.0, 1.0,
            1.0, 0.0,
            1.0, 1.0,
        ]),
        gl.STATIC_DRAW
    );

    // Create a texture and bing it to the gl context
    const texture = gl.createTexture();
    gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture);

    // Set the parameters so we can render any size image.
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_S, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_T, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);

    // Upload the tile image to the texture
    gl.texImage2D(
        gl.TEXTURE_2D,
        0,
        gl.RGBA,
        gl.RGBA,
        gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE,
        tileImage
    );

    // lookup uniforms
    var resolutionLocation = gl.getUniformLocation(program, 'u_resolution');
    var textureSizeLocation = gl.getUniformLocation(program, 'u_textureSize');

    // Tell WebGL how to convert from clip space to pixels
    gl.viewport(0, 0, gl.canvas.width, gl.canvas.height);

    // Tell it to use our program (pair of shaders)
    gl.useProgram(program);

    // Turn on the position attribute
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray(positionLocation);
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, positionBuffer);
    gl.vertexAttribPointer(positionLocation, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);

    // Turn on the texcoord attribute
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray(texcoordLocation);
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, texcoordBuffer);
    gl.vertexAttribPointer(texcoordLocation, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);

    // set the resolution and size of image
    gl.uniform2f(resolutionLocation, gl.canvas.width, gl.canvas.height);
    gl.uniform2f(textureSizeLocation, 256, 256);

    // bind frame buffer and draw arrays - draw TO the framebuffer?
    gl.bindFramebuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, fb);
    gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, 6);

    // Unbind framebuffer and draw...to the canvas?
    gl.bindFramebuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, null);
    gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, 6);
}
```

It is in the last few lines that I get confused.  The reason I know this is not working, is because if I put an artificial delay on each image load, you can see that each image is drawn to the canvas, but when the next one is drawn, the previous one disappears.

#### [Codesandbox demonstrating the issue](https://codesandbox.io/s/webgl-issues-with-framebuffer-ler3tx?file=/src/index.ts)

I have read many discussions on this.  In [WebGL display framebuffer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16287481/webgl-display-framebuffer), where [gman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/128511/gman) shows how to render to a framebuffer, then to the screen, for a single image.  The question [How to work with framebuffers in webgl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41824631/how-to-work-with-framebuffers-in-webgl) is very similar as well.  Most of the questions I've found have been either like this - rendering a simple single image to a framebuffer, then to the screen - or far beyond my level at this point, i.e. using a framebuffer to render to the faces of a spinning cube.  I can't seem to find any information on how to take simple 2d images, and render them to a webgl canvas in an async way.

I have also seen several recommendations to draw images to a 2d canvas, and use that as the source of a singular 2d texture.  For example, in the question [Can I create big texture from other small textures in webgl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61144041/can-i-create-big-texture-from-other-small-textures-in-webgl), gman recommends:

> If you have to do it at runtime for some reason then the easiest way to combine images into a single texture is to first load all your images, then use the canvas 2D api to draw them into a 2D canvas, then use that canvas as a source for texImage2D in WebGL

I don't understand *why* this is preferable.

How can I take these images async and stitch them together within a single webgl canvas?

**Appendix:**

```js
export function setRectangle(
    gl: WebGLRenderingContext,
    x: number,
    y: number,
    width: number,
    height: number
) {
    const x1 = x,
        x2 = x + width,
        y1 = y,
        y2 = y + height;

    gl.bufferData(
        gl.ARRAY_BUFFER,
        // prettier-ignore
        new Float32Array([
      x1, y1, 
      x2, y1, 
      x1, y2, 
      x1, y2, 
      x2, y1, 
      x2, y2]),
        gl.STATIC_DRAW
    );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a short answer, there is a simple fix, use:

```js
canvas.getContext("webgl", { preserveDrawingBuffer: true })
```

instead of

```js
canvas.getContext("webgl")
```

You can also get rid of all the framebuffer stuff, it is not actually doing anything in your program. You are rendering *to* the framebuffer, then you are rendering *to* the canvas, but you are not rendering from the framebuffer to the canvas. This is mostly explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41832778/392025) but it might not be clear that   with the `framebufferTexture2D` call you are saying that the framebuffer will render *to* the given texture, which you will need to later use as a source again. In your code there is no separation between the texture you are rendering to the framebuffer and the texture you want to "store" all the tiles in.

So why does the fix above work? Ignoring all the framebuffer stuff (which, again, does nothing in your program), you are rendering to the canvas across multiple frames. WebGL by default clears the canvas between frames unless the `preserveDrawingBuffer` flag is set, explaining why the previous tiles you rendered disappear every time you draw another one. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27814683/392025).

---

**Edit: how to actually make use of the framebuffer?**

To make this work with the framebuffer as intended, a couple of changes need to be made.

1. You created `targetTexture`, i.e. the texture to which you want to render the composed tile. What is its size and format? This is never specified and GL does not infer it; these parameters can in general differ from the main canvas you are drawing to.

   ```js
   const targetTexture = gl.createTexture();
   gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, targetTexture);
   gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA,
       512, 512, 0,
       gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, null);
   gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_S, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
   gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_T, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
   gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);
   gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);
   ```

   You can refer to the documentation of [`texImage2D`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebGLRenderingContext/texImage2D) for the parameters. They are similar to your existing `texImage2D` call, but the width and height must be provided, because we are passing `null` for the texture "source"—there is no texture yet, we just want GL to create an empty one for us.
2. In the `render` function, you want to perform two draw calls, corresponding to the two `drawArrays` calls you already have. These draw calls should have the uniforms and framebuffers set differently from one another:

   1. The framebuffer for the first call must be bound to `fb` to draw to it, then for the second call to `null` to draw to the canvas. (Already done in your code.)
   2. The texture for the first call must be `texture` (the new tile to be rendered), then for the second call `targetTexture` to make use of the framebuffer.

   ```js
   // before the second drawArrays call
   gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, targetTexture);
   ```

   3. To make things scale correctly, the `textureSizeLocation` uniform should be set to the framebuffer resolution for the second draw call:

   ```js
   // before the second drawArrays call
   gl.uniform2f(textureSizeLocation, 512, 512);
   ```

   4. The position buffer must specify a tile/quarter of the framebuffer in the first call, but the full canvas in the second call.

   ```js
   // before the second drawArrays call
   gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, positionBuffer);
   setRectangle(
     gl,
     0,
     0,
     gl.canvas.width,
     gl.canvas.height
   );
   ```

   5. (This inverts the image vertically, somewhere a sign needs to be flipped, for example in the previous point.)

This works, but let me also note that many of the operations done in `render` do not need to be done every time: for example, the `program` only needs to be attached once, the uniform and buffer locations can only be looked up once, etc etc. Data you put into attribute buffers also stays there over calls. (Unless there are other, unrelated GL calls that might take place in between the `render` calls: in which case, at least re-binding the program might be a good idea.)

Comment: You said "you are not rendering from the framebuffer to the canvas"- right. So how *do* I do that?  From your answer I think you understand what I'm trying to do here (yay).  As for using `preserveDrawingBuffer: true`, that was essentially the [solution to my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76204529/12010984), and it does indeed work.  But this question is more about understanding framebuffers, and how they can be used to intake and combine textures, then render to a final output texture and back to the canvas.  How can I do that (especially within the context of my code)?

Comment: This works exactly as I need.  When applying some kind of image processing (i.e. even a simple blur using each pixel's neighbor), it also really shows that using `preserveDrawingBuffer: true` is not the same, and not as good, as using the framebuffer.  Because when using `preserveDrawingBuffer: true`, each texture is blurred, but there are artifacts near the images' edges.  Using the framebuffer eliminates that.  I am certainly seeing the image is flipped vertically.  Why is that happening?  I was able to fix it with some modification to my `gl.buggerData` coordinates, but why is it flipped?

Comment: @SethLutske The blurriness might also be due to smaller resolution: you force the rendering to happen into the canvas size, whereas with a framebuffer you can choose a texture of an appropriate size. As for the flip, I am not sure, but this should be easy to figure out if you work your way through all the steps on paper. Generally this happens to me because (somewhat confusingly) when rendering vertices, up is Y=1 and down is Y=-1, but in texture coordinates, up is V=0 and down is V=1.